# Resolve CLR Type from DataContract.Namespace?

Tags: wcf, clr, namespaces, datacontract

I'm a newbie whitebelt with WCF.

I have a namespace: http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System/ArgumentException.

I'm looking to take that string and convert it into a CLR type so that I end up with typeof(ArgumentException).

Is this possible? :)

Thank you,
MichaelD

Answer (score 0):

Check out Activator.CreateInstance().  Here's an example of its usage:

```
dim obj as Object = Activator.CreateInstance("ArgumentException")
```

In your case you can parse the type name out of the namespace and pass it as a parameter to CreateInstance().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Comment: I'm familiar with this method/class.  However, I'm wanting a way of passing in the provided URI as a whole without any parsing involved.  There is something somewhere in the framework that allows this.  I know it. :)

Comment: I'm not aware of any built in framework methods to do this.  But you can accomplish it by combining the above method with reflection.  According to this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045.aspx - all CLR types have the same namespace format.  Any other namespace can be assumed to belong to your custom data contracts.

But if you find a framework solution, please let me know!